# How to prevent a PHP upload script from overwriting existing files?

Tags: php, file

Been working my PHP upload script myself, but got stuck with prevent overwriting existing file, how to do it. Please require tips and explanation. And also please if my way to handle upload is good, if not please advise and give tips.

```
$destination = 'C:/upload_test/';
$max=75200;
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
$fileTaille= $_FILES['image']['size'];
if ($fileTaille==true) {
 if ($fileTaille > $max) {
    echo "Your file is too large, select a file smaller than";
    exit(include 'form.php');
   }
 }
   else {
    echo "No file selected";
    exit(include 'form.php');
   }
}

$file_type=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

 if ($file_type==true) {
   echo "File is an image - " .$file_type["mime"]." ";
 }
  else{
    echo "Could not get file type";
  }

$fileType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$allowed = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);

 if (!in_array($fileType, $allowed)) {
   echo "File type not accepted, Only JPEG file allowed";
   exit(include 'form.php');
 }

$clean_file = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9\.\_-]/i", " ", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
 $fileName = $destination . basename($clean_file);
 if (file_exists($fileName)) {
   echo "File already exist";
   exit(include 'form.php');
 }

}

if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination . $_FILES['image']['name']); 

  if ($result == true) {
  echo "file moved "." ";
  }else
    {
    echo "Could not move filed";
    }
$permission = chmod($destination . $clean_file, 0644);
  if ($permission==false) {
    echo "No permission to the file";
  }
   else
   {
    echo "permission given";
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: TIP: Read the [manual page on file upload in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) I note most obviously you are not checking for `['error']` anywhere

Comment: Also you are trying to upload to a folder that I assume is outside your DocumentRoot. Try changing that to a subfolder of your site rather than a totally seperate folder, at least until you get it working.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah i upload outside my DocumentRoot only for testing on local computer..

Answer (score 0):

Best practise in my opinion is to make a sha256 of the file and then save it, this way you don't overwrite files and also you don't save duplicate files.

**How to do it:**

1. Upload the files to a temporary directory
2. Hash the file and get the sha256 string.
3. Rename the file and copy to upload folder.

**Example:**

```
$clean_file = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9\.\_-]/i", " ", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$fileName = hash_file('sha256', $clean_file);
rename($clean_file, $fileName.$extention);
```

Comment: I wouldn't preserve the extension - although there should be an explicit check for PHP files and other server executables, and files should be uploaded to an area where PHP files are not web reachable, nevertheless, dropping the extension entirely is a good habit to get into.

Comment: @halfer I dont really get your point.. Could you please show me how with codes?

Comment: @rebelfreak: do you wish to serve these files from the web? If so, you'll need to keep the extensions (unless you don't mind serving them with dynamic PHP scripts, but that's quite slow).

Comment: @Arjun Thanks but i dont get the $extention, you mention. what value thats variable hold?

Comment: @rebelfreak it holds the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are searching for and the file you are saving have different names. You are searching for a file with the name `$clean_file` but saving `$_FILES['image']['name']` instead.  You should update your code to save it as `$clean_file`:

```
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],
    $destination . $clean_file
);
```